# sql oracle search by multiple terms in business object report

Tags: sql, oracle, business-objects

I am writing a report where i would like the end user to be able to search by multiple terms (ie. UK, CZ)

but my code it does not fetch any results

```
 like @variable('2. COUNTRY (UK, CZ, AT or use % for all)')
```

It works when just using just one term (ie. UK) but not when the user tries to search for more than one value.

I have tried using different statements before the variable but still get no results.

Is a search like this possible?

I'm writing this for Business Objects 5

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to perform a wildcard search (by using the `LIKE` keyword) in combination with a prompt (I take it it's a multi-value prompt).

Lets go through a few possible scenarios:

1. Wildcard

   - Example: the user enters `%` in the prompt.
   - SQL translation: `Country LIKE '%'`
   - Result: the query returns all records due to the wildcard
2. Single-value

   - Example: the user enters `UK` in the prompt.
   - SQL translation: `Country LIKE 'UK'`
   - Result: the query returns all records with the `Country` column matching the value `UK`
3. Multiple values

   - Example: the user selects `UK` and `AT` in the prompt.
   - SQL translation: `Country LIKE 'UK,AT'`
   - Result: the query returns **no records** because there is no record that contains the value `UK,AT` (literally) for the `Country` column.

What you're trying to do, as far as I can determine, is to allow the user to select multiple values or skip the selection altogether and return all values (for which you used the combination of the `LIKE` keyword and `%` wildcard).

However, with multiple values, you need to use the `IN` keyword instead. In current versions of BusinessObjects (you're using a *very* old version), it's possible to make prompts optional.

As you don't have this feature, the only alternative is to create a universe condition in which you build a `CASE` around your `@prompt` function, to determine if the user entered a % or selected multiple values and then construct your `WHERE` clause accordingly.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.businessobjectstips.com/tips/web-intelligence/prompt-functions-the-next-step-optional-prompts/) for an example how to build such a condition.